# Primeng beta 10/Angular2 RC4 data table styleing does not show up

Tags: primeng

I started playing with Primeng to get some of the UI needed for my app. The one currently working with is the datatable. I am trying to create a dashboard which is styled conditionally. The following is the snapshot of what I need to achieve but cannot get the styling to show up. 
[image]

Here is my code. The code still does not consider the condition but I even cannot get the cells in the trend column to have a different color. 
Here are my trials using primeng beta 10:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="perfData" >
            <p-column field="Title" header="Title"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Curr Test" header="Curr Test"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Trend" header="Trend" [style.background-color]="blue">

            </p-column>
            <p-column field="Prev Test" header="Prev Test"></p-column>

 </p-dataTable>
```

I even tried the template pattern as has been demonstrated by primefaces but no luck:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="perfData" >
            <p-column field="Title" header="Title"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Curr Test" header="Curr Test"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Trend" header="Trend">
                <template let-col let-row="rowData">
                    <span [style.background-color]="blue">{{row[col.field]}}</span>
                </template>
            </p-column>
            <p-column field="Prev Test" header="Prev Test"></p-column>
 </p-dataTable>
```

Both of these codes results to the same below snapshot for my table. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using webpack and have included the css files required for the primeui in my index html as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/theme.css" />
```

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way if you don't want the header color.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="perfData" >
   <p-column field="Title" header="Title"></p-column>
   <p-column field="Curr Test" header="Curr Test"></p-column>
   <p-column field="Trend" header="Trend">
     <template let-col let-row="rowData">
        <div [style.background-color]="(row[col.field] == header) ? 'none' : 'blue'">
          <span>{{ row[col.field] }}</span>
        </div>
     </template>
   </p-column>
   <p-column field="Prev Test" header="Prev Test"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

You should modify the CSS of the div tag in a way that it will fit into the cell. Try using negative margins. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Gayan,
I did try the template and worked but not with this syntax you have, with this syntax mine does not work. I used <div style="background-color: #92D050"> {{row[col.field]}} </div> and the good thing is that the header would not be affected when using template this way. 
As you mentioned I gotta play with the css to make the div fit into cells.

Comment: You're welcome @Afi. For me this worked. I was using PrimeNG Beta 12 which was recently released. So I think that's the reason it didn't work.

Comment: @Afi: See my answer to a related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/42013275/7307355 for an example of how to make the div fit into the cell and eliminate the surrounding white space.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it this way.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="perfData" >
     <p-column field="Title" header="Title"></p-column>
     <p-column field="Curr Test" header="Curr Test"></p-column>
     <p-column field="Trend" header="Trend" [style]="{'background-color':'blue'}">
     </p-column>
     <p-column field="Prev Test" header="Prev Test"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks Gayan for your response,
putting the style this way worked but this will color the whole column including the header.