# How to add style class to p-dataTable row

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

We're using p-dataTable from PrimeNG 1.0.0-beta.16

I want to add a style to the row when a value is true.
I figured it out how to do this with the cell, but I need the whole row the change its background.

```
<p-dataTable [hidden]="loading" [value]="timePeriods" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400px" rowStyleClass="missingPeriod">
    <p-column field="StartDate" header="Begindatum" sortable="false">
        <template let-col let-timePeriod="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <span [class.missingPeriod]="!timePeriod.IsNext">{{timePeriod.StartDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="EndDate" header="Einddatum" sortable="false">
        <template let-col let-timePeriod="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <span>{{timePeriod.EndDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span> 
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

`<span [class.missingPeriod]="!timePeriod.IsNext">` is working but `rowStyleClass="missingPeriod"` is not.

Please advice.

**Updated syntax**:

Updated to v1.0.1

```
<p-dataTable [hidden]="loading" [rowStyleClass]="customRowClass" [value]="timePeriods" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400px">
    <p-column field="StartDate" header="Begindatum" sortable="false">
        <template let-col let-timePeriod="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <span [class.missingPeriod]="!timePeriod.IsNext">{{timePeriod.StartDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="EndDate" header="Einddatum" sortable="false">
        <template let-col let-timePeriod="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <span>{{timePeriod.EndDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

And the typescript:

```
public customRowClass(rowData, rowIndex): string {
    console.log("In customRowClass");
    console.log(rowData);
    console.log(rowIndex);
    return "";
}
```

Nothing inside `customRowClass` is logged. It seems to me this method isn't called.

Comment: Where did you find RowStyleClass?  I don't see it in the datatable's list of attributes on priming's site.

Comment: I found RowStyleClass using Google. It might be for an older version of PrimeNG. Their links to samples aren't working, so their website is not very helpful.

Comment: Did you try to use the `styleClass` attribute ?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

In version 1.1.3 of PrimeNg this is fixed. So this question can be closed.

Comment: it is still a legitimate 'how-to' question. no need to close

Answer (score 24):

`rowStyleClass` works a bit differently than you'd think; it takes a function as it's input, that returns a string (the CSS class name).  It's listed in the [PrimeNG DataTable docs](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).

In my HTML I've got:

```
<p-dataTable [rowStyleClass]="lookupRowStyleClass" ...>
```

In the component:

```
lookupRowStyleClass(rowData: User) {
    return rowData.accountDisabled ? 'disabled-account-row' : '';
}
```

In a global CSS file:

```
/* TODO: this should really be in the component's CSS file, but it doesn't seem to apply to the PrimeNG data table properly there */
.disabled-account-row {
    /* TODO: first try this without '!important', but you might need it */
    color: silver !important;
}
```

If this doesn't help, you need to **upgrade to a more recent version**.  PrimeNG 1.0.0 RC5 is out as of November 2016.

Comment: I also saw this commit https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1296 suggesting a different syntax. This one looks better because my row needs to be colored based on the row data. Not a global object like your `user`. I just update using `npm update --save` but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I've just posted my latest code in my topic start, using the sample on GitHub.

Comment: @PaulMeems Try upgrading to a more recent version of PrimeNG like 1.0.0 RC5 if you haven't already. This approach requires a more recent version. Your code sample looks good.

Comment: I've already updated to v1.0.1 but no luck. Do you have a working sample?

Comment: @PaulMeems Ah okay, yeah that's a very up to date version of PrimeNG.  The code that I mentioned in this answer is what I've been using, and works.  I wonder if it would be possible to set breakpoints in the datatable class, https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/datatable/datatable.ts.

Comment: I am interested in changing the color of a row that is selected.  I have a checkbox that allows the row to be selected.  How do I change from the standard blue to a gray.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `scrollable="true"` is the cause of this. When `scrollable` is set to `true`, a different template is used which doesn't have the binding for `getRowStyleClass`.

Here you can see the `<tr>` for a table that is **not** scrollable has a binding for `getRowStyleClass`: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/02e88b16e811a10d8842deb1f5e354bfb295d4c9/components/datatable/datatable.ts#L180

But the `<tr>` for the scrollable table does not have the binding: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/02e88b16e811a10d8842deb1f5e354bfb295d4c9/components/datatable/datatable.ts#L257

You can see both cases in [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/25NZ7M?p=preview) and I have posted an issue [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1613).

I don't see any reason the method can't be used on scrollable tables, so I have submitted a PR with a fix for this that you can monitor [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/1614).

Comment: Thanks you for finding the problem. I've subscribed to your issue and will wait for the solution. When your issue is resolved I will mark your post as the answer.

Comment: Looks like the fix was merged in: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/1614 . Not sure how quickly a new release will go out.