# How to add ngClass type functionality to a row of Primeng p-datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have been using Primeng for a while.

I have used Primeng Datatable (p-dataTable) in my component. The component what I am trying to do is inbox. I read messages from DB to a model named 'Message' in Angular 2. There is a field in model named Read. Its used as a flag. Its Boolean. My requirement is if Read is false, entire row elements should be in one colour, say color1. If Read is true, entire row elements should be another color, say color2.

I know how to do the same using ngClass.

Can someone please suggest me how I can do the same using p-dataTable. I tried many ways I can by referring many sites & didn't find any. **What I want is a functionality similar to ngClass in p-dataTable**

Here is my code

**In HTML**

```
<p-dataTable [rowStyleClass]="readFlag" [value]="message" >
        <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}"  selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column field="SenderUserId"  header="From" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column class="icon-mandatory" field="Subject" header="Message"></p-column>
        <p-column field="MessageDate" header="Time" [sortable]="true">
            <template let-col let-message="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                <span>{{message.MessageDate | date: 'medium'}}</span>
            </template>
        </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

**In Component**

```
readFlag(rowData: Message) { return rowData.Read ? 'inbox-Read' : 'inbox-Unread' ; }
```

**Message Model**

```
export class Message 
{
    public Subject: string;
    public Body: string;
    public MessageDate: any;
    public Read: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us examples of what you've tried, and why they don't work?

Comment: Could you add some actual code?

Comment: @Adam 
when i gave the function as 
    **readFlag(rowData: Message) { return rowData.Read ? 'inbox-Read' : '' ; }**
inbox-Read class is getting applied for all rows of the table. But I want that class to be applied only to row which satisfies the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer for my question

**In HTML**

```
<p-dataTable [rowStyleClass]="applyReadFlagStyle" [value]="message">
        <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}"  selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column field="SenderUserId"  header="From" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="Subject" header="Message"></p-column>
        <p-column field="MessageDate" header="Time" [sortable]="true">
            <template let-col let-message="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                <span>{{message.MessageDate | date: 'medium'}}</span>
            </template>
</p-dataTable>
```

**In Component**

```
applyReadFlagStyle(rowData: Message): string {
    return rowData.IsRead ? 'inbox-Read': 'inbox-UnRead'  ;
}
```

Comment: Seems there is no difference between code block in  your answer and the question, or I cant see ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowstyle class attribute. It is there in the primeng docs. It takes a function as argument . The function should return the class to be set or try [attr.class]="condition? 'color1':'color2'"

Refer : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528666/how-to-add-style-class-to-p-datatable-row

Comment: is that the only way to bring ngClass-like functionality in p-dataTable?

Comment: i read about rowstyle class.
what I saw is it takes a function name as its value and inside that function value ternary operator should be used to return class name as shown below.

**in HTML**
<p-dataTable [rowStyleClass]="readFlag" >

**in Component**
readFlag(rowData: Message) {
        return rowData.Read ? 'inbox-Read' : 'inbox-Unread' ;
    }